# Ionic + Parse, need to parse Json to csv and send email with attachment

Tags: angularjs, json, parse-platform, ionic-framework, mailgun

I'm looking for implementation for parsing Json object to csv and send it to a custom email address with the csv file as attachment.

Currently I'm using ionic + Mailgun for sending emails without attachments, but Mailgun dosen't support sending files.

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real shortcut here. You'll need to iterate over your data set, generate the `csv` string and then write to file using cordova file plugin. Then you can either prompt the user to send the email by using the plugin `cordova-plugin-email-composer` to attach the file you've just saved OR find a service that lets you `POST` a file as part of the request, or write your own backend code to receive `POST` requests with the file to send the emails.